# Remove tags without removing content

Tags: node.js, gulp

I'm looking for a Gulp module which is capable of deleting all `<div>` tags and closing tags, without removing the content/children of said `<div>`.

Does such a thing exist?

**Example code:**

```html
<div id="MACONTAINER" contenteditable="true" maconstraint="ITEM.IMAGE1 <> ''" mashowalllanguages="FALSE">
  <tr>
    <td class="img">
      <div id="MASECTION" contenteditable="true" maconstraint="ITEM.URL1 <> '' AND ITEM.PROMOCODE1 <> ''" mashowalllanguages="FALSE">
        <a href="~PROBE(101)~" title="~ITEM.ALT1~">
          <img width="580" height="~ITEM.IMAGE1HEIGHT~" alt="~ITEM.ALT1~" src="~ITEM.IMAGE1~" />
        </a>
      </div>
      <div id="MASECTION" contenteditable="true" maconstraint="ITEM.URL1 <> '' AND ITEM.PROMOCODE1 = ''" mashowalllanguages="FALSE">
        <a href="~PROBE(105)~" title="~ITEM.ALT1~">
          <img width="580" height="~ITEM.IMAGE1HEIGHT~" alt="~ITEM.ALT1~" src="~ITEM.IMAGE1~" />
        </a>
      </div>
      <div id="MASECTION" contenteditable="true" maconstraint="ITEM.URL1 = ''" mashowalllanguages="FALSE">
        <img width="580" height="~ITEM.IMAGE1HEIGHT~" alt="~ITEM.ALT1~" src="~ITEM.IMAGE1~" />
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</div>
```

**Desired code:**

```html
<tr>
  <td class="img">
    <a href="~PROBE(101)~" title="~ITEM.ALT1~">
      <img width="580" height="~ITEM.IMAGE1HEIGHT~" alt="~ITEM.ALT1~" src="~ITEM.IMAGE1~" />
    </a>
    <a href="~PROBE(105)~" title="~ITEM.ALT1~">
      <img width="580" height="~ITEM.IMAGE1HEIGHT~" alt="~ITEM.ALT1~" src="~ITEM.IMAGE1~" />
    </a>
    <img width="580" height="~ITEM.IMAGE1HEIGHT~" alt="~ITEM.ALT1~" src="~ITEM.IMAGE1~" />
  </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use plugins like [gulp-replace](https://github.com/lazd/gulp-replace) which uses regexes:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    replace = require('gulp-replace');

gulp.task('strip-tags', function() {
    return gulp.src('template.html')
        .pipe(replace(/<div.*?id=.MACONTAINER..*>((?:.|\s)+)<\/div>/im, '$1'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});
```

But regexes are a bit brittle for that kind of task imho...

You could also roll your own "plugin" and do it that way :

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    through = require('through2'),
    cheerio = require('cheerio');

gulp.task('strip-tags2', function() {
    return gulp.src('template.html')
        .pipe(through.obj(function(file, enc, cb) {
            var $ = cheerio.load(file.contents),
                extract = $('#MACONTAINER').children().html();

            file.contents = new Buffer(extract);

            cb(null, file);
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});
```

Comment: Hey, thanks!

I did use you first method but with different RegEx's

`.pipe(replaceSpecific(/<\/div>/g, ''))
    .pipe(replaceSpecific(/<div.*">/g, ''))`

I couldn't really figure out the second proposition but I figured this would do the trick.